# Existe plugin de crud para wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, crud

Preciso de um *plugin* que pegue as informações de um formulário e insira ela no banco de dados, também quero poder alterar, consultar e excluir esses dados em uma página admin.

Podem ser *plugins* distintos para cada função.

Entendo mediamente de PHP, mas não sou familiarizado com o WP, o que complica, pois acho ele muito limitado, mas preciso usá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin para **CRUDs** genéricos dentro do WordPress não é muito necessário, quando se tem o bom uso da classe global [$wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

[Crie você mesmo seus plugins](http://www.escolawp.com/2012/01/como-criar-plugins-para-wordpress-parte-i/) manipulando a `wpdb Class`. No entanto, existem [plugins(pagos)](http://codecanyon.net/item/xcrud-data-management-system-php-crud/3215400) para fins genéricos, mas talvez não atenda a situações específicas.

Comment: Também acho que plugins não são muito necessários neste caso, a classe wpdb te permite fazer CRUDs e a calsse WP_List_Table para criar a página no admin para gerenciar os dados.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o @Lollipop mencionou, o uso da `wpdb` pode resolver o seu problema. Mas, se tratando de plugins, acredito que o [Contact Form DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/) possa lhe dar alguma luz. Eu já usei ele juntamente com o [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) em vários projetos, e ele funciona muito bem. A interface dele permite que você consulte e exclua inputs dos forms diretamente pelo painel de administração do WP. Quanto a alteração, as coisas se complicam. Eu sei que existe um [plugin pago](http://cfdbplugin.com/?page_id=459) pra isso, mas nunca usei (e nem precisei).